# Created excel, but not able to open using rssheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, excel

I want to create a excel sheet which should be looks like normal excel file and able to open the excel sheet in ios app using document controller.

Currently I am using rssheet from github, but this does not support to open it with document controller. It is able to create a excel type sheet and append data but can't open it in the app using document controller. When I tried to open it, it showed a message saying that it is not supported.

Please if anyone tried excel in obj-c iOS app, let me know how to do that .

Comment: Same problem ..any solution  ??